# In $\mathbb R^n$, why does $f_k=\chi_{\{\mathbf x: |\mathbf x| < k\}}$ not converge globally in measure to $f=1$?

Tags: real-analysis

In $\mathbb R^n$, why does $f_k=\chi_{\{\mathbf x: |\mathbf x| < k\}}$ not [converge globally in measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_in_measure#Definitions) to $f=1$? I think as $k\to +\infty$, $f_k = 1$ in a ball of radius $+\infty$ centered at $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because for any $1>\epsilon>0$ and any $k$:
$$\mu(\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: |f-f_k|\geq\epsilon\}) = \mu(\mathbb{R}^n)-\mu(\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: |f-f_k|<\epsilon\}) = \infty $$
As $\mu(\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: |f-f_k|<\epsilon\}) = \mu(\{x: |x|<k\})<\infty$

Where $\mu$ is Lebesgue's measure.

Comment: Then we take the limit?

Comment: @user398843 If you take limit of infinities, what do you get? Infinity.